# Is there any way to not include image name in ECS in terraform state?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

we have a pipeline that upgrades servers based on qa needing a new release etc. and that is QUICK deploy to ECS with an aws command currently.  This results an issues with terraform

currently our developer put in a hack to read the version from ECS and put in terraform files so it does not downgrade our version.  This results in 15 microservices all saying the image is different while the AWS image is correct.

process ->

1. tf state has version 123 (tf state 123, aws state 123, files show variable placeholder)
2. we upgrade qa(or prod) to version 124 (tf state 123, aws state 124, fils show variable placeholder)
3. we upgrade qa to verison 125 (tf state 123, aws state 124, files show variable placeholder)
4. when we apply terraform now, we have 15 services screaming they are different :( and that tf state 123 does not match aws state of 125

We do not want to upgrade through terraform as that takes 5-10 minutes vs. deploying in 30 seconds.  Is there a way in terraform to just put a 'placeholder' there so when comparing to terraform state, it says no differences and does not try to change our image version.

How to deal with that situation?

I have not thought of anything to try.  I am expecting tf to only show me real changes and not deal with software version changes at all.

Comment: Uhm, it sounds rather confusing. You want to preserve the image version? Always or in some cases?

Comment: @MarkoE on devops deploys, we always want to preserve image version.   software deploys are fast and way more frequent and need to be fast.

Comment: software deploys are done outside terraform for speed and frequency.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74394598/8343484?

Comment: ouch.  not possible it is :( .  I am so sad... hacking continues.

Answer (score 1):

You can have terraform [look up](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ecr_image) the "most recent" image from ECR whenever you run `terraform apply`. Then Terraform will detect that something has changed outside of the Terraform state, but it will be smart enough to see that the change that was made is the same as the new desired state, so Terraform won't overwrite your deployment.

---

Alternatively, some judicious use of the terraform `--target` flag could get your ECS deployments working through Terraform almost as fast as whatever you are doing with your "quick" deployments.

Answer (score 0):

You can have second ":latest" tag added to your latest image that you want to deploy, and configure your terraform code to deploy "latest" tag. However this requires you to disable tag immutability on your ECR repositories, which means that you by mistake can overwrite version tag for your images, which can have undesired results.